# How to use the "this" keyword to call a

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, this

How do I write a function in JavaScript that receives an array and a function(convertFunc). The function calls convertFunc for every element of the array.
The element should be accessed via the *this* keyword.
The function should return an array of the return values of the convertFunc calls?
e.g.

```
function(array, convertFunc() {  // array=[1,2,3]
    return this+10;
}
```

Should return [11,12,13]

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Posting homework questions is not wrong *per se*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10839/167534). However, this is not a good question because it doesn't show much research effort. See [Writing the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) for ideas on how to improve your question.

Comment: Do people use this for homework? And, they're actually teaching JavaScript now in school... wow. :)

Answer (score 2):

1. Create the function, e.g. `function map(arr, convertFunc) {`
2. Iterate over all elements of the array `arr`.
3. Tip: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call
4. Return an array containing all results from the function calls.
5. `}`

Figure the exact details out by yourself, good luck :)

Comment: This is the only answer that accounts for the actual problem stated: creating a function that receives an array and a function as arguments.

Answer (score 0):

`array.map(callback[, thisObject]);` might fit for you.

Example:

```
var nums = [1,2,3];

function FuncName(x)
{
    return x+10;
}

var result = nums.map(FuncName); //[11,12,13]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you are looking for extending the Array object

```
Array.prototype.convertFunc = function() {

var arr = this, i; // As you want array is access using the this keyword.

for(i = 0; i<arr.length; i++)
{
    arr[i] = arr[i] + 10;
}

return arr;
}

var myArray = [1,2,3];


 // Call like this
 myArray.convertFunc();
```

Fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/PYxzj/

**Update**

And to answer your question try this

```
    // Pass your array and a function as parameter
function arrayModify(array, convertFunc)
{
  return array.convertFunc();
}


// This function iterates your array and adds 10 to each element.
var arrayAddFunction = function() {

   var arr = this, i;
   for(i = 0; i<arr.length; i++)
   {
      arr[i] = arr[i] + 10;
   }

return arr;
}

// Extending the array object
Array.prototype.convertFunc = arrayAddFunction;

var aa = [1,2,3];

// As you want send your array and a function as parameters to another function 
alert(arrayModify(aa,arrayAddFunction)); // -> [11, 12, 13]
```

Fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/qzB4e/

Comment: I assume because it does not answer the question. You did not explain how to create a function which takes an array and a callback and executes the callback for each of the array elements. Your solution is inferior...

Comment: That works but is unnecessarily complex and confusing. The function you pass to `arrayModify` does nothing. It "looks" like the parameter `convertFunc` and the name `convertFunc` in `return array.convertFunc();` are somehow related, but they are not at all. I'm sorry, but this is just a huge mess. Extending the array prototype is the wrong way here.

Comment: @kiranvj, modifying native object prototypes is often considered bad practice.

Comment: Yes, I also think the code is little messy. Should I delete it? or will it be useful to anyone?

Answer (score 0):

```
var myFunc = function(fn) {  // array=[1,2,3]
    return fn(this);
};

myFunc.call(arr,function convertFunc(){
    return this+10;
});
```

But, to solve your exact problem:

```
var arr = [1,2,3], addTen = function(){
    for (var l=this.length;l--;) this[l] += 10;
};

addTen.call(arr);
```

Comment: I would recommend against prototyping the native Array object... but, that works as well (as another answer suggests).